# Заменить все нечетные элементы

Tags: c++, математика

Помогите с написание метода: найти максимальное и минимальное значение и найденным максимальным значением заменить все нечетные значения в массиве.

Вот нахождение максимального и минимального значения.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 20, 40, 30, 50, 22, 16, 15, 88, 21, 14, 17, 44, 25, 55, 66, 77, 89, 63, 11 };
    int(*pArr)[sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr)] = &arr;
    unsigned minIndex = 0;
    unsigned maxIndex = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 1; i < sizeof(*pArr) / sizeof(**pArr); ++i) {
        if (pArr[0][i] < pArr[0][minIndex]) {
            minIndex = i;
            continue;
        }
        if (pArr[0][i] > pArr[0][maxIndex]) {
            maxIndex = i;
            continue;
        }
    }
    cout << "minimum: " << (*pArr)[minIndex] << endl;
    cout << "maximum: " << (*pArr)[maxIndex] << endl;
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: @Akina исправил

Comment: Нечётные перебираются циклом `for(int i=1;i<size;i+=2)`.

Comment: @Akina Нужны нечётные значения, а не нечётные индексы

Comment: @MBo Когда есть нечётный индекс, по нему можно получить/изменить соответствующее значение... наверное.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну после того как нашли, просто проходите таким же циклом и заменяете:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); ++i) {
    if (arr[i]%2) arr[i] = arr[maxIndex];
```

Comment: А можно через метод пожалуйста?

Comment: Ну сами вынесите, это же элементарно!